# How to send get request with forward slash instead of question mark?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a PHP application, in which I need to use forward slash in place of question mark in get request. Like:

> www.example.com/article?aid=10&aname=my-article

should be changed to

> www.example.com/article/10/my-article

Following is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ articles?q=$1 [L,QSA,B]
```

I have tried a lot, but not able to find solution. How can this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ page.php?level1=$1&level2=$2 [L]
```

The `level` then describe your full url separated by the symbol `/`

Then in the page hypothetically called `page.php` you can do:

```
$firstParameter = $_REQUEST["level1"];
```

---

In your case you can do:

```
RewriteRule article/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ article?aid=$1&aname=$2 [L]
```

Then your url will be `/article/foo/bar`

**N.B.**

I normally use `RewriteBase /` to have the basic rewrite with `/`, 
It is' to put so:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: I want to convert /article?aid=foo&aname=bar to /article/foo/bar

Comment: @VishalSuri - You can do anything with this. You can have as many levels as you want. Page.php is just one example of the landing page where you can take the information. If your file is called "article" no problem, then the name of "levels" call them as you wish, such as `aid`, `aname`. I have update my post

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to rewrite **/article/foo/bar** to **/article?aid=foo&aname=bar** 
Add the following right bellow **RewriteEngine on**

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ /article?aid=$1&aname=$2 [L,QSA,B]
```